# How to use Markit on Demand API to request a XML file?

Tags: javascript, php, xml

I'm trying to write an application which takes a user input and output a XML file as a result. I'm using PHP and html, also interacting with a API called Markit on Demand.

Here's the php code I've come up with:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

 function getXML($stockName) {
  // document.write("Inside function");
  // document.write("<br />");
  // document.write($stockName);
  // document.write("<br />");

  var connect = new XMLHttpRequest();
  connect.open('GET',"http://dev.markitondemand.com/MODApis/Api/v2/Lookup/xml?input="+$stockName,false);

  connect.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","text/xml");
  connect.send();
  var xmlData = connect.responseXML;
  // var xmlData2 = connect.responseText;
  document.write(xmlData);
  document.write("<br />");
  // document.write(xmlData2);
  // document.write("<br />");

  if(!xmlData)
  {
    document.write("funck");
    document.write("<br />");
    xmlData=(new DOMParser()).parseFromString(xml.responseText,"text/xml");
  }
  else{ return xmlData;}
 }
 </script>
</head>

<body>
 <?php
  // $stockName = json_encode($_POST['stockName']);
  $stockName = $_POST['stockName'];
  echo $stockName . "</br>";

  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>getXML('$stockName');</script>";
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

The $stockName is what I have from my html function which is just a input box where user can input the stockName that they want to lookup, and I use this php code to catch the name and send the request to get the result in XML format.

However, my code won't work, as I try to output the the xml result but get nothing.

Can someone help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The  $stockName can be something like "GE".